# R data table unique record count based on all combination of a given list of values from 2 columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` in R as below

```
Col1          Col2         
Col1Value1    Col2Value1   
Col1Value1    Col2Value2
Col1Value1    Col2Value3
Col1Value2    Col2Value1   
Col1Value2    Col2Value3
Col1Value3    Col2Value1
Col1Value3    Col2Value2
Col1Value3    Col2Value3
```

I want to get the count of records for each combination between given values in `Col1 - (Col1Value1,Col1Value2)` against values in `Col2 - Col1(Col2Value1,Col2Value2)` and if no records for a combination then return 0

`counts <- dt[, length(unique(Col2)), by=.(Col1, Col2)]`

The above code returns all combinations, but

```
- A combination with 0 records are not returned
- Not able to restrict to a given list
```

Expected result

```
Col1           Col2        Count
Col1Value1     Col2Value1    1
Col1Value1     Col2Value2    1
Col1Value2     Col2Value1    1
Col1Value2     Col2Value2    0
```

Comment: For combinations with 0 records, you might have to first create the rows, all with zero values, to then overwrite those that have more than 0. That makes me wonder if you really need to keep both columns separate, or if you could benefit from creating a new column that results from adding Col1 and Col2, as comma-separated characters (e.g. "2, 3"). That way you can first have an inventory of all the possible combinations, and then count the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R, you can do:

```
data.frame(table(dt))

        Var1       Var2 Freq
1 Col1Value1 Col2Value1    1
2 Col1Value2 Col2Value1    1
3 Col1Value3 Col2Value1    1
4 Col1Value1 Col2Value2    1
5 Col1Value2 Col2Value2    0
6 Col1Value3 Col2Value2    1
7 Col1Value1 Col2Value3    1
8 Col1Value2 Col2Value3    1
9 Col1Value3 Col2Value3    1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DT[CJ(Col1, Col2, unique = TRUE), on = .(Col1, Col2), .(count = .N), by = .EACHI]

#          Col1       Col2 count
# 1: Col1Value1 Col2Value1     1
# 2: Col1Value1 Col2Value2     1
# 3: Col1Value1 Col2Value3     1
# 4: Col1Value2 Col2Value1     1
# 5: Col1Value2 Col2Value2     0
# 6: Col1Value2 Col2Value3     1
# 7: Col1Value3 Col2Value1     1
# 8: Col1Value3 Col2Value2     1
# 9: Col1Value3 Col2Value3     1
```

Data

```
DT <- fread(
  "Col1          Col2         
  Col1Value1    Col2Value1   
  Col1Value1    Col2Value2
  Col1Value1    Col2Value3
  Col1Value2    Col2Value1   
  Col1Value2    Col2Value3
  Col1Value3    Col2Value1
  Col1Value3    Col2Value2
  Col1Value3    Col2Value3"
)
```

If you want to limit combinations then you could filter beforehand as Harshal did using `dplyr`:

```
a <- c("Col1Value1", "Col1Value2")
b <- c("Col2Value1", "Col2Value2")
DT[Col1 %in% a & Col2 %in% b
   ][CJ(Col1, Col2, unique = TRUE), on = .(Col1, Col2), .(count = .N), by = .EACHI]
```

Comment: Thank you . I thought requirement was for limited combinations from set of all combinations hence that approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` like so:

```
data.table(with(dt, table(Col1, Col2)))

         Col1       Col2 N
1: Col1Value1 Col2Value1 1
2: Col1Value2 Col2Value1 1
3: Col1Value3 Col2Value1 1
4: Col1Value1 Col2Value2 1
5: Col1Value2 Col2Value2 0
6: Col1Value3 Col2Value2 1
7: Col1Value1 Col2Value3 1
8: Col1Value2 Col2Value3 1
9: Col1Value3 Col2Value3 1
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- setDT(read.table(text="Col1          Col2         
                 Col1Value1    Col2Value1   
                 Col1Value1    Col2Value2
                 Col1Value1    Col2Value3
                 Col1Value2    Col2Value1   
                 Col1Value2    Col2Value3
                 Col1Value3    Col2Value1
                 Col1Value3    Col2Value2
                 Col1Value3    Col2Value3", header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
a<-c("Col1Value1", "Col1Value2")
b<-c("Col2Value1", "Col2Value2")

df2<-df %>% select(Col1, Col2) %>% filter(Col1 %in% a) %>% filter(Col2 %in% b)  %>% group_by(Col1, Col2) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% as.data.frame()

expand.grid(a,b) %>% left_join(df2, by = c("Var1"="Col1", "Var2"="Col2")) %>% mutate(count2 = ifelse(is.na(count), 0, count)) %>% select(-count)
```

Below is the output:

```
        Var1       Var2 count2
1 Col1Value1 Col2Value1      1
2 Col1Value2 Col2Value1      1
3 Col1Value1 Col2Value2      1
4 Col1Value2 Col2Value2      0
```